# Asymptotic Expansions of Symbols Vs Asymptotic Expansion of Pseudodifferential Operators

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis, pseudo-differential-operators, microlocal-analysis

Let $a_k(x,\xi)$ be a family of symbols on $\mathbf{R}^d \times \mathbf{R}^d$, where $a_k$ has order $\alpha_k$, and $\lim_{k \to \infty} \alpha_k = -\infty$. Then for another symbol $a(x,\xi)$, we write

$$ a(x,\xi) \sim \sum_{k = 0}^\infty a_k(x,\xi) $$

if the order of the symbols $r_N(x,\xi) = a(x,\xi) - \sum_{k = 0}^N a_k(x,\xi)$ tends to $-\infty$ as $N \to \infty$.

Conversely, given a family of pseudodifferential operators $\{ T_k \}$, and another operator $T$, we write

$$ T \sim \sum_{k = 0}^\infty T_k $$

if for any $\alpha \in \mathbf{R}$, there exists $N_0$ such that for $N \geq N_0$, the operators $R_N = T - \sum_{k = 0}^N T_k$ can be expressed in terms of a symbol of order $\alpha$, i.e. there exists $a_N$ of order $\alpha$ such that for any smooth, compactly supported function $f$,

$$ R_N f(x) = \int a_N(x,\xi) e^{2 \pi i \xi \cdot (y-x)} f(y)\; dy. $$

Are these two notions `equivalent' in some sense, i.e. what can we say about a family of symbols $\{ a_k \}$ such that we have an asymptotic expansion

$$ T_a \sim \sum_{k = 0}^\infty T_{a_k}. $$

Is is then true that

$$ a \sim \sum_{k = 0}^\infty a_k\; \text{?} $$

If not, can we say something weaker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Later, I realized the simple observation that the operator $T = a(x,D)$, when applied to the distribution $u(y) = e^{2 \pi i \xi \cdot y}$, gives the output $Tu(x) = a(x,\xi)$. Thus one may recover the symbol completely from the pseudodifferential operator, which means the two notions of asymptotic correspond completely.